# Python Iteration for String Values then Join the strings found from a Multi-Page Mailing List

Tags: python, list

Good Day,
I have a file that contains multiple pages of letters to different individuals. I need to extract 2 distinct values, mailID and MailType from each letter then join them together for a new value, mailacct, and append it under the mailing address information on the letter. Eventually the loops will reside within a function, but for right now here is what I'm working through.

ASK: I need to iterate through each mailing letter for mailID and mailType to create mailAcct, then append at the bottom of the mailing information:

```
(BEFORE) : Each Letter has the following data at the top of the page, 

Name:  Smith, Jon
Date of Birth:  1900-01-01
Mailing Address:  123 Fake Street
Address Suite:  0
MailID:  A123456789098765
Name 2:  Smith, Jane
Mail Date:  2020-12-09 11:22:36
Mail Type:  CR

I have create the following loop to pull the data, but I am only able to retrieve the first iteration of the values. 


with open("mailText", "r")
    mail = mailText.read()

# Gather the mailID from pages #

for iM in mail:
    resultMail = re.compile(r'MailID: (.*)')
    iM = resultMail.findall(str(mail))

# Gather the mailType from pages #

for iT in mail:
    resultMail = re.compile(r'MailType: (.*)')
    iT = resultMail.findall(str(mail))

mailDict = {iM[0]:iT[0]}

print("The mail Account Number is: ", mailDict)


(AFTER) : Each Letter should include the created "mailAcct" number after running through the code, 

Name:  Smith, Jon
Date of Birth:  1900-01-01
Mailing Address:  123 Fake Street
Address Suite:  0
MailID:  A123456789098765
Name 2:  Smith, Jane
Mail Date:  2020-12-09 11:22:36
Mail Type:  CR
***MailAcct: A123456789098765CR***
```

I have also tried creating a single loop for both values using,

```
for iM, IT in mail:
    iM_resultMail = re.compile(r'MailID: (.*))
    iT_resultMail = re.compile(r'Mail Type: (.*))

    iM = iM_resultMail.findall(str(mail))
    iT = iT_resultMail.findall(str(mail))

mailDict = {iM[], iT[]}

print("The mail Account Number is: ", mailDict)
```

Either way, I'm not able to get the desired looped output to validate that I can move to the next step in the program of adding/appending to the bottom of the address information.

Any thoughts or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Here are some pointers: 


1. Please don't use the same name for the loop variable and the variable to store the result as well. <br>
2. If you know that there is going to be exactly one ID for each entry, it's better to use `re.match`. <br>
3. If you know the range of values that they ID can take, use a more specific regex that constrains the number of possible matches.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for finding MailID from a single e-mail.

I have made some assumptions. You can customise it to your liking.

- There is exactly 1 ID following line starting with "MailID:"
- `MailID:` is always followed by exactly **two** whitespaces before the actual ID.
- The ID is formed by exactly one single uppercase letter from the English alphabet followed by exactly 15 digits.

```
>>> import re
>>> example = """
... Name:  Smith, Jon
... Date of Birth:  1900-01-01
... Mailing Address:  123 Fake Street
... Address Suite:  0
... MailID:  A123456789098765
... Name 2:  Smith, Jane
... Mail Date:  2020-12-09 11:22:36
... Mail Type:  CR"""
>>>
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'MailID:\s\s([A-Z][0-9]{15})') # Example: Exactly one uppercase letter followed by 15 digits
>>> match = pattern.search(example)
>>> match.group(1)
'A123456789098765'
>>>
```

I have used what's know as a [capturing group](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping) [the pair of `()` of around `([A-Z][0-9]{15})`] to extract just the ID. If you want the entire line, get the "zeroth" group.

```
>>> match.group(0)
'MailID:  A123456789098765'
```

Comment: Thanks for the previous suggestions and input I'll play around with this and see how it might help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate in users' info and combine the ID and TYPE, something like this should work for you.

- get all IDs and TYPES first
- iterate in all IDs
- add the ACCOUNT to a list

```
mail = open("mailText", "r").read()

iM_resultMail = re.compile(r'MailID:  (.*)')
iT_resultMail = re.compile(r'Mail Type:  (.*)')

iM = iM_resultMail.findall(str(mail))
iT = iT_resultMail.findall(str(mail))

mail_accounts = []
for i in range(len(iM)):
    mail_accounts.append(iM[i]+ iT[i])
```

Comment: Hi Salman I tried this and I modified it a bit because I was getting an invalid argument error. I updated it to a function, but I'm getting only 1 returned result. I am also only getting one result without the function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with. I used snippets from each of the suggested answers, or at least the inspiration from the suggestions.

```
import re

with open("results_view_report_DEV_1.txt", "a+") as sourceFile:
sourceFile.seek(0)
content = sourceFile.read()
sourceFile.seek(0)

newContent = sourceFile.readlines()

accn_pattern = re.compile(r'Accession Number:\s+([A-Z][0-9]{15})')
md_pattern = re.compile(r'Study Modality:\s+([A-Z]{2,3})')

accn = accn_pattern.findall(content)
md = md_pattern.findall(content)

for i in range(len(accn)):
    visID = accn[i] + md[i]
    visInfo = "\n"+ "VisitID: " + visID
    print(visInfo)
```